# Visually Tag/Mark a Window

Tags: user-interface

I'm looking for a way to visually mark or tag a window (any OS) so that it stands out.

A while back, I accidentally replaced a live production database containing thousands of records with an empty dev version, simply because the two instances of Enterprise Manager looked identical to one another. I'd like to avoid that in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I'm aware of, but perhaps a [virtual desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop) system for your OS of choice would help keep the separation a little better for you.

Comment: That, and make sure the background of the production desktop is very distinctive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TOAD for your db access you can set a custom colour for each of your connections. ([List of Quest products here](http://www.quest.com/products/all-products.aspx) scroll down page to the TOAD links)
The colour appears as a border around each TOAD window (at least it did on the Windows version I used in my last job)
I set production dbs to RED, pre-production to orange, and dev to green.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't restrict your question, I'll answer with my solution to this type of problem. I often am logged into multiple different machines with [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) as different users (including as `root`). If I have a window that I want to distinguish from the others, for example when I need to make sure I know I am typing commands as root, I change the background of the window to a different colour. A window that is mostly red really stands out as being something extraordinary.